# How to set win + E shortcut for dolphin file browser

Tags: ubuntu, archlinux, kde-plasma

I have installed Dolphin file browser(dolphin 18.12.3) on plasma(5.15.2) (ArchLinux). I would like to know how to set win + E (meta + E) shortcut to launch Dolphin browser. I already tried setting it as shortcut in [System Settings->Global Shortcuts->Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5Jaa.png) Launchers. But shortcut is not working as expected.
Is there an other way to set it up? Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- right-click launcher/start button in panel
- select *Edit Applications*, the KDE Menu Editor opens
- find *Dolphin* in *System* folder in the tree view and select it
- switch to *Advanced* tab
- click on the *None* button for *Current shortcut key* to record a different key
- hit `Meta+E` keys, it should appear in the button
- click *Save* in toolbar and done!